# Convert multiline string into a single line

Tags: vb.net

I would like to do the following thing but I can't - Textbox1.Text

```
line 1 = 1 2
line 2 = 3 4
line 3 = 1 7
line 4 = 4 9
```

I want to return this to look like this: yes, and with doubles like 1 1 and so on

Textbox1.Text >Expected Output

```
line 1 = 1
line 2 = 2
line 3 = 3
line 4 = 4
line 5 = 1
line 6 = 7
line 7 = 4
line 8 = 9
```

each digit must be on a separate line. that is, on each line that digit, there are now 2 digits on a line.

Code:

```
source = source.Replace(vbLf, "").Replace(vbCr, "")
```

Comment: Looks like you want to replace space characters with a line-break, not the other way around. Try something like `TextBox1.Text = TextBox1.Text.Replace(" ", Environment.NewLine)`. If that's not what you want, please try to explain more because the title of your question and your code are inconsistent of your expected output.

Comment: each digit must be on a separate line. that is, on each line that digit, there are now 2 digits on a line.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> each digit must be on a separate line. that is, on each line that
>   digit, there are now 2 digits on a line.

I'm assuming you don't actually have `line x =` in your TextBox.

Rather you have:

```
1 2
3 4
1 7
4 9
```

and want:

```
1
2
3
4
1
7
4
9
```

If so, here's a one-liner that can do it for you...

```
Private Sub Button1_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click
    TextBox1.Lines = String.Join(" ", TextBox1.Lines).Split(" ".ToCharArray(), StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries)
End Sub
```

Comment: Wait...do you actually have `line 1 = ` in the TextBox?

Comment: @Idel_Mind [Nope](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62203012/convert-multiline-string-into-a-single-line#comment110012805_62203374) :)

Comment: `.ToCharArray()` is redundant

Comment: @Fabio, without `ToCharArray()`, I get an "overload resolution failed" error...

Comment: You can simplify it with `SelectMany` to `TextBox.Lines = TextBox.Lines.SelectMany(Function(line) line.Split(" ", StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries).ToArray()`

Comment: True, but some people find it harder to understand `SelectMany`...while I'm guessing most people can understand `String.Join()` followed by `String.Split()`.

Comment: `SelectMany` tells other reader what you are doing without diving into details how it is done, for example `SelectMany` - "Convert from one to many", `Select` - "Convert from one to another", `Aggregate` - Convert from many to one.  Where with `Join` and `Split` reader need to dive into the details and understand why we joining something together just to split it later ;)

Comment: Sorry, "harder to understand" is a weak point of mine ;), I think we shouldn't aim our code to the lower point of knowledge, but grow and learn all together. Aim to "Better know a framework" ;)

Answer (score 2):

You can split original text into values and then combine them together into new lines of text

```
textbox.Lines = textbox.Lines.
    SelectMany(Function(ln) ln.Split(" "c, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries).
    ToArray()
```

Comment: I think it is written in C ++, and does not work properly I should change it for VB, also on each line appears only the digit (number), no (line 1 = number appears). (I put it there to show as an example).

Comment: ok i will try to do it works thanks but it has some errors :(

Comment: It's very nice code @Fabio, he just doesn't actually have `line x = ` in the data.  =/

Comment: I up-voted your answer for the obvious effort you put into it.  ;)

Comment: Agree with Fabio, `SelectMany` provides more info for the developer who didn't write this code.